# angular-2-dropdown-multiselect - XHR error (404 Not Found)

Tags: angular, multi-select

I am tryng to use angular-2-multiselect-dropdown but I am getting the below error -

[errro image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lod9d.png)

My package.json file look like below -

[image: package.json]

app.module.ts file below  -

[image: app.module.ts]

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. [Check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrgbkn?file=src/app/app.component.ts). If possible share the code. So that I can help you.

Comment: Try this.. stop server, run *npm cache clean* and *npm install*.

Comment: i have solved this issue by updating system.config.js file.

But now getting different error. I have tried to use other component as well. Same thing.

i have update the question. ANy help would be appreciated

Comment: It's bit difficult to reproduce this kind of issue. Could you please share minimum reproducible code/details. Check the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)